# Transformar decimal em timestamp

Tags: db2

Ola,
Estou fazendo um projeto onde devo trabalhar com `DB2`. Existe uma tabela onde foram feitas duas colunas do tipo `DECIMAL`.Para ser mais exato segue o código de criação:

```
[DATA_VARIAZIONE] [decimal](8, 0) NOT NULL,
[ORA_VARIAZIONE] [decimal](6, 0) NOT NULL
```

E o que quero fazer é retornar uma coluna do tipo `TIMESTAMP` tendo como base esses dois valores. 
Exemplo de valores desses campos:

```
ORA_VARIAZIONE | DATA_VARIAZIONE|
---------------|----------------|
192416         |20180427        |
```

O resultado esperado é que esses valores sejam retornados como uma coluna unica de tipo `TIMESTAMP`. Ou seja

```
DATA_ORA_VARIAZIONE|
2018-04-27-19.24.16|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei essa solução para o problema mas não sei se é a melhor, segue o código:

```
select TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(substr(dt,1,4) || '-' || substr(dt,5,2) || '-' ||substr(dt,7,2) || ' '||substr(dt,9,2)||':'||substr(dt,11,2)||':'||substr(dt,13,2)||':' , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as DATA_ORA_VARIAZIONE
from (
    select CONCAT(right( '00000000'||RTRIM(DATA_VARIAZIONE),8), right('000000'|| ORA_VARIAZIONE,6)) dt 
    FROM TABLE
    )as tabela
```